# curl - get cookies into file

Tags: php, curl

There are 3 files in one folder:

curl.php:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/url.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

curl_exec($ch);
```

url.php:

```
setcookie('test', 'foo', time()+60*60*24, '/');
```

cookies.txt: (empty)

When I run `curl.php`, I expect that cookie will be saved in `cookies.txt`.
But nothing happens.

What is wrong with this, why it does not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have permission to write the file in that directory with the user that it executes as?

If no cookies have been received, there will be no file saved and you should note that the cookies are saved to the file when the handle is closed.

It might be necessary to give the absolute path of the text file where the cookies should be saved to be sure you know where they end up.

Comment: `curl_close($ch)` does not help (and I think it close it anyway). But it actually can read cookies. If I add `echo $_COOKIE['test']` it echoes it. So while script is running, file is used. But when it ends, it gets emptied. Is it how it should be?

Comment: I've found problem. You should use absolute pass for coockies file. Otherwise it saves somewhere else (where it could be?).

Comment: @Qiao Thanks for your comment, I had the same problem with paths. Thanks !!

Comment: @Qiao Not always happends like that. I'd try on several servers and usually fails to write to correct path, so it's a good practice to define always the full path ie. using PHP constants.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR** - The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

So you need to call `curl_close($ch)`.

Comment: Don't agree with that. No need to close curl to do anything with it. You can leave open with 0 problem, but memory load.

Answer (score 2):

Just define path.

Change `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . 'cookies.txt');` and should work.

And remember. COOKIEJAR is to save cookies, and COOKIEFILE is to load again to work with them.

Happy cURL ;P